# How can I add form fields to a php/MySQL Login form which are not in the database to send it via an email

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I currently have a simple login form that uses an "accesscode" to gain access to a part of my site and an "admin" and "password" to enter the administrative section. There is no personal data stored here so security is not paramount.

The login works fine and I can access the site.

When some one logs in, it goes to a "loading page" that sends me an email through php to say that it has been opened.

What I am trying to do is add 2 form fields to the login form that do not exist in the database but the data inputted into the fields is sent via the php email.

The fields I am adding are firstname and lastname. The accesscode and password fields work as normal. 
The whole login process works but I cannot figure out how to pass the form data from firstname and lastname to the email section.

Form Code

```
<!-- start login form -->
<div class="contact-form">
<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; }?>
<form method="POST" action="" role="form">
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label for="name">Access Code*</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="accesscode" placeholder="">
<i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label for="name">First Name*</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="">
<i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label for="name">Last Name*</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="">
<i class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
<label for="name">Password (if applicable)</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="">
<i class="fa fa-key form-control-feedback"></i>
</div>

<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-default"/></td>
</form>
</div>
<!-- end login form -->
```

PHP code that responds to the form - this is what I have tried so far

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("config.php");
//Getting Input value

//process first form
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
  $accesscode=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['accesscode']);
  $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
  $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
  if(empty($accesscode)){
  $error= 'Fields are Mandatory';
  }else{
 //Checking Login Detail
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT*FROM patientres WHERE accesscode='$accesscode' AND password='$password'");
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 if($count==1){
    $_SESSION['patientres']=array(
   'accesscode'=>$row['accesscode'],
   'password'=>$row['password'],
   'role'=>$row['role'],
   'libname'=>$row['libname'],
   'url'=>$row['url']
   );
   $url=$_SESSION['patientres']['url'];
   $firstname=$_SESSION['patientres']['firstname'];
   $lastname=$_SESSION['patientres']['lastname'];
   //Redirecting User Based on Role
    header("Location: " . $row['url']);

 }
 else{
 $error='<div class="alert alert-danger fade in" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button><strong>Invalid Access Code</strong><br><br>Check your code and try again.<br>If your code is correct and does not work, please <a href="******" class="alert-link">contact us.</a>        </div>';
 }
}
}
?>
```

This is my updated php code that I have tried to convert to prepared statements, but it loads the login page, but on submit I just get a white screen. I feel that the header redirect is not working.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("config.php");
//Getting Input value

//process first form

//if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        $accesscode=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['accesscode']);
        $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
        if(empty($accesscode))
           {
           $error= 'Fields are Mandatory';
           }else
           {
           // Prepare our SQL, preparing the SQL statement will prevent SQL injection.
           $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM patientres WHERE accesscode = ? AND password =?");
           $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $_POST['accesscode'], $_POST['password']);
           $stmt -> execute();
           $result = $stmt -> get_result();
           if($result->num_rows === 0) exit('No rows');
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                $_SESSION['patientres']=array(
                    'accesscode'=>$row['accesscode'],
                    'password'=>$row['password'],
                    'role'=>$row['role'],
                    'libname'=>$row['libname'],
                    'url'=>$row['url']
                 );
                //$url=$_SESSION['patientres']['url'];

                //Redirecting User Based on Role
                header("Location: " . $row['url']);    
                 }
            $stmt->close();
            }
    }
?>
```

This then goes to another page which processes this script

```
<?php
session_start();
//Checking User Logged or Not
if(empty($_SESSION['patientres'])){
 header('index.php');
}
?>
<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

$ipdat = @json_decode(file_get_contents( 
"http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip));

$to      = 'someemail@email.com';
$subject = 'Patient Resource Access by: ' . $_SESSION['patientres']['accesscode'];
$message = "Resource Access by: " . $_SESSION['patientres']['accesscode'] . "\n\nUser: " .     $_SESSION['patientres']['firstname'] ."\n\nAt: " . date('d/m/Y, H:i:s')."\n\nCountry: " . $ipdat->geoplugin_countryName . "\nCity: ". $ipdat->geoplugin_city . "\nLatitude: ". $ipdat->geoplugin_latitude . "\nLongitude: ". $ipdat->geoplugin_longitude . "\nTimezone: ". $ipdat->geoplugin_timezone;

$message = "Message sent from IP: $ip\n\n" .$message;

//$message. = date('m/d/Y, H:i:s');
$headers = 'From: Some Resources' . "\r\n" .
//'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

//redirect
header( "refresh:4;url=../functional.php" );?>
```

So the only thing I cannot figure out how to do is pass the firstname and lastname info from the form to that it gets sent in the email but otherwise not used.

Thanks

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in, and there are [authentication libraries](http://phprbac.net/) you can use. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: "Security is not paramount" is the wrong attitude to have. If you write code this full of holes and it gets shipped by accident you could end up in huge trouble. Even if this is test code, writing it properly does not take more effort. The correct approach saves time and fuss. It also means someone can't hijack your box to do all sorts of nefarious things using an automatic exploit scanner, which is always a nice bonus.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Hi Tadman, Thanks for the feedback. I am new to php and mysql and I have been teaching myself. How can I convert what I have to parameterized queries or do I need to recode the whole segment?

Comment: Links in the comments above. The `bind_param` function documentation has multiple examples.

Comment: hi tadman, i have endeavoured to udpate the code to prepared statements but as stated in my edit, it does not login anymore, it just loads a white screen with no error message.

Comment: I can see multiple syntax errors at first glance here. If you make consistent use of whitespace and indentation, your code will be much easier to read, and it will be much easier to spot errors like extra braces or broken if/else statements.

Comment: That's improved, but there's still problems here like the use of plain-text passwords. It should be impossible by design to fetch a record knowing the password alone. That's what `password_hash` and `password_verify` are for, but more importantly, what authentication libraries have already solved.

Comment: i agree with the password hash and im in the process of doing it for the administrator - were not using that function at the moment as it is just an internal site for staff to access resources for work. I am still doing something incorrect but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: we just have accesscodes at present. If I do not put any values in a click Login - it goes to a plain white page and no source can be seen. If I do put a valid "accesscode" in, it does the same.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure out how to do what my initial question asked

I added this to the initial part of my php login script

```
//if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        $firstname=$_POST['firstname']; <---- this line here
        $lastname=$_POST['lastname']; <--- this line here
        $accesscode=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['accesscode']);
        $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']);
.....
if($count==1)
        {
            $_SESSION['patientres']=array(
            'accesscode'=>$row['accesscode'],
            'password'=>$row['password'],
            'role'=>$row['role'],
            'libname'=>$row['libname'],
            'url'=>$row['url']
            );
            $url=$_SESSION['patientres']['url'];
            $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname']; <-- this line here
            $_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname']; <-- this line here
            //Redirecting User Based on Role
            header("Location: " . $row['url']);
```

I then added the following to my email code

```
$message = "Resource Access by: " . $_SESSION['patientres']['accesscode'] . "\n\nUser: " . $_SESSION['firstname'] ." ". $_SESSION['lastname'] ."\n\nAt:
```

THanks for everyones help. I am still slwoly trying to get everything in prepared statements.